# Clean install of Apache but can't access it via lan client

Tags: networking, server, apache2, php, iptables

I've been fighting this issue for a couple days now and am at whits end, so any help would be great. I have several computers in the office. One is now a Ubuntu Server that I'm setting up for a web-based application. The rest are a mix of Windows 7 and Apples. I can't access the Ubuntu LAMP through the other client browsers with the IP. I get a 'Page Not Found' error after spinning for a while. I'm not interested in the Ubuntu server being accessible from WAN, only LAN.

Setup on the Ubuntu Server: I nuked a hard drive and installed a fresh version of 15.04 so it's the only OS on the system. I installed xrdp to enable remote desktop control. That installed without a hitch. I ran this `apt-get install lamp-server^` to install the LAMP stack. That installed without a hitch. I haven't changed any of the `conf` files. This is what I show when I run `ufw status`:

```
root@ubuntuserver:/# ufw status
Status: inactive
```

This is what my `iptables` looks like when I run `iptables -L`:

```
root@ubuntuserver:/# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target    prot  opt  source          destination
ACCEPT    tcp   --   anywhere        anywhere           tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT    tcp   --   anywhere        anywhere           tcp dpt:http

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target    prot  opt  source          destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target    prot  opt  source          destination
```

This is what `netstat` shows for `netstat -ntlp`:

```
root@ubuntuserver:/# netstat -ntlp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17201/mysqld   
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1227/dnsmasq   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11437/sshd     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5910          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1742/Xvnc      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3350          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1594/xrdp-sesman
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3389            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1590/xrdp      
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      19199/apache2  
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      11437/sshd
```

Sometimes if I `service apache2 reload` then I can access the `It Works` page from my Windows 7 computer once. But only once. If I try to navigate to the `phpinfo.php` page, it times out. Or vice versa if I try to access the `phpinfo.php` page first, then I can't get to the `It Works` page.

On the Ubuntu server, I can access any number of pages through `localhost` and the IP `172.19.0.15`. I don't have that same kind of success via other computers in the office, though. And because it's a web-based app that they'll need to access, I need that access.

What am I missing?

***EDIT 1***

Taking Ben's advice, I've edited the `ports.conf` file to read:

```
#Listen 80
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
```

I've restarted the Apache2 service and this is what the netstat now looks like:

```
tcp    0    0  0.0.0.0:80    0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN     9342/apache2
```

However, I'm still getting the same behavior. I was able to access the `phpinfo.php` or the `It Works!` page once, then I couldn't navigate to another page.

I did read about editing the `<Directory>` entry in `apache2.conf`. Currently it reads:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

But again, I haven't changed this from the default. That and the localhost works fine... Any other thoughts?

***EDIT 2***

Here's the contents of my `000-default.conf` file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port t$
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.

    #LogLevel info ssl:warn
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

I restarted the server and still can't access it using the IP from a LAN computer.

Comment: `Listen 0.0.0.0:80` binds it to ipv4 addresses, it might be worth going back to `Listen 80` while trouble shooting.  What does your Virtual hosts directive look like.  The Ubuntu default they should be in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`

Comment: I changed the Listen back to just 80 and have included the contents of the Virtual Hosts directive above. Please see the edit of the OP. Thanks Cargo

Comment: your setup looks like it should accept all connections on port 80 at all addresses. Could there be another issue in the network? duplicate IP addy? VHost setup? router/gateway not letting the traffic through? can you ping it from another comp?

Comment: I had similar symptoms in U16 immediately after upgrading from U14, though everything worked under U14.  In my case, whilst UFW was inactive, I had iptables setting firewall rules at boot (something I setup when I did my initial install on U10), and it turned out that somehow I had missed opening ports 80 and 443.  What made this difficult to debug was that, for some reason, under U14, everything worked fine and I had forgotten about iptables thinking UFW was doing all the work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with your firewall but with your apache configuration.

As, muru explained correctly, you can see by this line:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      19199/apache2
```

that apache is listening on [both](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/bind.html#ipv6) ipv4 and ipv6.

Since you mentioned it is working from localhost I would suggest checking your network configuration.

Comment: Please see the edit above. I changed it, however, I still can't access the Ubuntu from a LAN client using a browser and the IP.

Comment: -1: This output indicates Apache listens on all interfaces. It shows only `::` because IPv4 is handled by [addresses mapped to IPv6](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/bind.html#ipv6), which works fine on Linux.

Comment: It ended up being a firewall that was upstream from me. Got that configured and things are working well now! Thanks for the tip!